# How to "interrupt" a function call?

Tags: c++, signals, gnu

I am doing a kind of shell: depending of the user's entry, I must call some function. I cannot modify the content of those called functions since my program is only a client and has no visibility of them.

But I want the possibility for the user to kill the call using `CTRL+C`. Here is the minimal code:

```
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

void do_thing(void)
{
    std::cout << "entering in do_thing()\n";
    while(42)
        ::sleep(1);
}

extern "C" {
    void signal_handler(int);
}

class Shell
{
    friend void signal_handler(int);

    public:
        static Shell & Instance(void)
        {
            static Shell    instance;
            return instance;
        }
        int run(void)
        {
            std::string     buff;
            while ((std::cin >> buff))
            {
                if (buff == "foo")
                    do_thing(); // this must be terminable
                else
                    std::cout << "(nothing)\n";
            }
            return 0;
        }

    private:
        Shell(void)
        {
            ::signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
        }
        void signal(int sig)
        {
            if (sig == SIGINT)
                ;// must terminal the function call
        }
};

extern "C" {
    void signal_handler(int sig)
    {
        Shell::Instance().signal(sig);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    return Shell::Instance().run();
}
```

I considered three possibilities:

- I tried to create a thread class derived from `std::thread`, with a `kill()` method that throws an exception. The function call is in a try-catch block. It works, but this is a bad solution since the destructor cannot be called, and the resource is never freed.
- I considered using `fork`, but I think it is an overkill to just get the possibility of interrupt a function call.
- I tried to throw an exception from the signal handler, but I saw that this is a bad idea since this is very compiler/OS dependent code.

How could you do the thing? What is the better solution?

Note: I deleted the old post because it was close requested, and took into consideration the C/C++ tags.

Comment: Did not I read this minutes ago?

Comment: One of the points of exceptions and stack unwinding is that objects should go out of scope and be destructed normally. Not that it matters anyway since the exception is thrown in your thread and not in the context of the thread that executes your "command".

Comment: It is not possible to abort a function call, nor it is possible to kill a thread (your `kill()` method cannot possibly do that---you seem to have an unusual definition of "works", and perhaps some kind of misunderstanding of C++ exceptions). The only (yes, the **the** the **only**) way to have an execution flow that can be aborted from the outside no matter what is to create a separate process for it. So yes, `fork()`.

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to use `fork` to create a new process that runs the "command". Then when you want to kill it just propagate the `CTRL-C` signal to the child process.

Comment: @n.m. When I said that "works", I meant the user can type and launch another command. And that's sad. A `fork` is too heavy for this purpose...

Comment: Sure he can, with or without your `kill()`. The question was how to kill a command, not how to run two commands in parallel.

Comment: I got the idea to launch an exception from within the thread, because when I delete that dynamically allocated thread, the programs crashes saying : `terminate called without an active exception [1] 16680 abort      ./Shell`.

Comment: "... and type another command". Sorry, but once you've called `TerminateThread`, `pthread_cancel` or a similar heavyhanded function, your whole process is an an unknown and unrecoverable state. The chief reason why you have such methods is to implement an "emergency save of the users work", so you can then exit & restart with a clean slate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, no, there is no standard why to interrupt a thread in C++. Threads run co-operatively and as such, they need to "give up" control.

*If the code for `do_thing` were modifiable*, then you can create a flag (atomic) to signal that the thread should give up and exit. This can be periodically checked by the thread and complete as required.

*Given the code for `do_thing` is not modifiable*, there is a small window of opportunity that can be used to "kill" or "cancel" the thread (albeit it won't be "standard" and support will be limited to targeted platforms).

`std::thread` offers a function to retrieve a [`native_handle()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle) that is implementation defined. Once obtained (and converted), it can be used to kill or cancel the thread.

- If pthreads are being used, see [`pthread_kill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html) (or [`pthread_cancel`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html) if supported by the target thread).
- On windows, see the [`TerminateThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

**Be warned**; aside from the platform specific code required, the thread terminations generally leave the objects on that thread in "limbo" and with them, the resources they control.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm under GNU/Linux (Debian) ; but the program may be used under others distro (like Ubuntu). However, it will be always compiled with `g++`

Comment: You will need to check the type returned by `native_handle()` for all the target types - it is implementation defined. But given they will most likely be pthread based, the `pthread_t` is most likely in all cases.

Comment: I think I will use the C pthread library, as you suggest. It seems fast and is portable, if I well read the documentation.

Comment: "the thread terminations generally leave the objects on that thread in "limbo" and with them, the resources they control" IOW, it's a recipe for disaster, don't touch.

Comment: Note also that `pthread_cancel` is cooperative (a thread will only be cancelled at specific cancellation points which the function in question may or may not call), and `pthread_kill` only *delivers a signal* to a specific thread and doesn't really do anything to *terminate* that specific thread.